# jquery find previous td with class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to find the first previous td with a class name and give me the content of that table cell.

I keep getting [object Object], result or undefined as the result instead of the html.

Here is a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pms6p9j3/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.Add', function (event, ui) {
    var classid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    var name = $(this).closest('td.itemName').html(); /* ISSUE */
    $('#cart .order-list').append('<li id="' + classid + '" name="' + classid + '"><div class="order-list-name">'  + name + '-' + classid + '</div></li>');
});
```

I've tried the below as well as a few other examples I've found on the web.

```
var name = $(this).prevAll('td.itemName:first').html();
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT :

As requested here is the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr id='1'>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class='itemName'>Item 1</td>
        <td>blah Blah</td>
        <td><a href='#' class='Add'> + </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='2'>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td class='itemName'>Item 2</td>
        <td>blah Blah</td>
        <td><a href='#' class='Add'> + </a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="cart" style="margin-top:80px;"> 
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class='block-info-left'>

                </div>
                <ul class="order-list"> 

                </ul> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you include some of the HTML in link with your search?

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings('td.itemName').html();` http://jsfiddle.net/pms6p9j3/2/

Comment: `.parent()` won't work if you have "sub-tags" in your `<td>` tags. You would at least need to use `.parent("td")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need in order to traverse through the DOM.

```
var name = $(this).parent().siblings('td.itemName').html();
```

Here's how it works:

- `$(this)` refers to `<a>`.
- `.parent` traverses to the `<td>` parent.
- `.siblings` traverses to the sibling `<td>` with the specified selector.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pms6p9j3/5/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can get the `td` tag that's a child of the closest `tr` and has the itemName class.

```
$(document).on('click', '.Add', function (event, ui) {
  var tr_tag = $(this).closest('tr'),
      classid = tr_tag.attr('id'),
      name = tr_tag.children('td.itemName').html();

  ...
});
```

Side Note: you should have a single `var` at the beginning of your functions. It works anywhere, but that's what really happens in JavaScript.

The `children()` only searches direct children of a tag. Use the `find()` function to search though all the descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Add', function (event) {
  var tdElements = $(this).parent().siblings();
  for(var i=tdElements.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(tdElements[i].className) {
      //has a className and is the "most previous"
    }
    else{
      //has no className
    }
  }
});
```

This would iterate the td elements and find the closest previous td with a className